# many NUL characters when reading streamed text file through serial

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an arduino that stores gps location with 1hz rate in a txt file terminated with \n every time. The file inside SD Card is this.

[image: Arduino Side Text File]

I wrote a c# console program that tries to read the stream for the serial port and append to a txt.

The arduino waits for the date of the file <050720> and then streams the txt to the serial port.

[image: Serial Port Terminal dumping the txt file]

When I try to read the serial for the PC side I get a result with a lot of NUL strings.
[image: dumped txt file PC Side]

**ARDUINO CODE FOR DUMP TO SERIAL**

```
    logfile = sd.open(f, O_READ);
    while (logfile.available()) {
      buffer = logfile.readStringUntil('\n');
      DEBUG_PORT.println(buffer);
    }
  }
  logfile.close();
```

**C# CODE FOR READING SERIAL AND APPENDING TO FILE**

```
  private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        byte[] buff = new byte[9600];
        _ = sp.BaseStream.Read(buff, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
        string response = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);
        AppendToFile(String.Format (response));
    }
    private static void AppendToFile(string toAppend)
    {
        string myFilePath = @"C:\temp\Test.txt";
        File.AppendAllText(myFilePath, toAppend + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

1. The serial ports connect settings are : *SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM19",115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);*
2. Should I try a different way to send the strings from arduino to serial?
3. Should I trim the NUL in the pc side procedure?

thanks

@edit

tried this and worked better.
Using `sp.ReadLine();` would be better for this instance?

```cs
byte[] buff = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
            sp.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
```

@edit 2

```cs
SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
string response = sp.ReadLine();
AppendToFile(String.Format (response));
```

but still got some weird output
[image]

@edit 3

So readline(); works fine and appendtofile function changed as not to add newline every line. Missing some lines though...

```cs
 private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string response = sp.ReadLine();
            AppendToFile(response);
        }
        private static void AppendToFile(string toAppend)
        {
            string myFilePath = @"C:\temp\Test.txt";
            File.AppendAllText(myFilePath, toAppend);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What does sp.BaseStream.Read  return?

Comment: `_ = sp.BaseStream.Read`  -- you're throwing away a *really* important value, which is how many bytes were actually read. If you call `Read` and enough data isn't available, it will read what's available and return, telling you how much it's read. You assume that it's filled up `buff`, but it probably hasn't! You need to pay attention to how much it says it's read, and only turn those bytes into text.

Comment: Either way, you're reading lines of text. Just use `sp.ReadLine()` -- much *much* easier

Comment: @canton7 I think that should be an answer, really.

Comment: @Fildor There are so many other answers saying how to read lines of text from a `SerialPort`: any answer will be a dup

Comment: @canton7 Then we should mark this as a dupe, right?

Comment: Sure, feel free to find a good candidate :)

Comment: Working on it ...

Comment: I am really searching two days in stackoverflow and didnt find the solution.

Comment: @Thodoris I believe you. As with many things, life is so much easier once you know the answer :) It's often a lot easier to track down a good pre-existing question for the same problem if you know what the problem *is*. Which means it's a lot easier for us than for you, and that's fine. I'm not blaming you for failing to find an answer.

Comment: Please edit, instead of commenting, if you have new info.

Comment: @Thodoris `byte[] buff = new byte[sp.BytesToRead]; sp.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);` is better but still flawed: you don't look at the value returned by `sp.Read`, so you don't know whether it's filled `buff` with bytes or not. Using either of the two approaches that HansPassant posted in the answer that @Fildor found are much better. `sp.ReadLine()` is the easiest of them all if the data you're reading is line-based (and your data is)

Comment: The last output doesn't look too bad, though. You got some extra newlines. You could check `response` with `if( !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(response) ) AppendToFile(response)` and of course check if `AppendToFile` adds some extra newlines. If it does and you prefer those, you need to strip `response` from newline chars before appending it.

Comment: It's much much *much* better to let the `SerialPort` tell you how many bytes it read, rather than throwing that information away and then trying to recover from the consequences. Also note that the approach of reading bytes and them throwing them through `Encoding.UTF8` will break if you actually ever get any non-ASCII characters. If there are nice APIs to work directly with characters, you should use them, because they take care of all of that complexity. Use `ReadLine()`

Comment: thanks everyone for the help. I think now the problem is the appendtofile function that add a newline every line

Comment: adding one more edit :)

Comment: You're reading in some newline characters over serial, and then adding your own newline characters in `AppendToFile`. Seriously, use `SerialPort.ReadLine()`. The code you're using at the moment **still has problems**, and I'm telling you how to fix them. That will also fix your newline issue as a side-effect.

Comment: @canton7 Yes I read your comments and try to implement them.

Comment: Note: `SerialPort.ReadLine()` will block the thread until `newline` characters are received.

Comment: The NUL values are coming from noise in your cable.  I'm guessing you are using a usb-serial cable, our's do it too.  The `SerialPort` class has a `DiscardNull` method.  Setting it to true will discard all NULs. `serialPort1.DiscardNull = true;`